# What is better to transform doing linear regression, response or explanatory variable(s)?

Tags: regression, data-transformation

Maybe it is a very basic question and already answered, but I could not find a clear answer.

My plots of response vs. predictors show "curved" relationship, and log-transformation can help to achieve linearity. But it helps either when I log-transform response variable or when I log-transform explanatory variables, as well. The distributions of them all are more or less close to normal.

So, what is better to transform, response or predictors, from statistical point of view? Or it doesn't matter for regression and I only need to seek to normal distributions?

(I see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13314/is-r2-useful-or-dangerous/) that when predictors are not transformed then R2 is related to the variance of the residuals and can be trusted. Is it the only reason?)

Comment: since you say that there is a curved relationship between the predictor and the response, have you considered a quadratic term in your regression model?

Comment: I tried square and root transformations; but if you mean adding squares of predictors to the regression equation, then no.

Comment: yes, if you see a curve linear relationship between predictor and response, then perhaps a model that contains a quadratic term, $X^2$ in one of the predictor terms would be a better fit.

Comment: if transforming either leads to a reasonable description of the mean, I'd focus on which one did a better job of describing the variance. What are your responses and predictors measuring?

Comment: My predictors are signals going through a medium with attenuation and response is the distance. Physical background of all that says that the dependence is logarithmic. @Glen_b

Comment: Can you write down what the physical background suggests the relationship is? Surely the physical background doesn't have an ambiguity about where the logs go!

Comment: @Glen_b Physics would lead to transforming predictors, however, then their distributions differ from normal, and R2 is less, regression is worse. I maybe would prefer to transform the response for better prediction (its distr. becomes closer to normal after transf.). So I want to understand _statistical_ rules for regression.

Comment: So ... distance becomes left skew after taking logs? What is the functional form of the expected relationship of the original variables? [Note that regression doesn't assume the response is unconditionally normal, and it doesn't assume the predictors are anything.]

Comment: @Glen_b The transformed response is not skewed, almost normal (log with some empiriclly found coeff.). [The original disributions](http://pp.vk.me/c407129/v407129874/6c39/9NLhYpU0DjQ.jpg) (the last is the response). All predictors are in linear relationship between each other (highly correlated) and in nonlinear with the response [(like this)](http://pp.vk.me/c10418/u17020874/153949434/x_9898cf38.jpg)

Comment: Thanks. However, there are no assumptions about the distributions of the predictors, so they may look like anything whatever, and it's not possible to tell from this whether the *conditional* distribution of the response is non-normal - you have there a plot of its unconditional distribution, about which no assumptions are made. In any case, if that was the conditional y-distribution, I would hardly be concerned by it at that sample size. I'd worry much more about likely heteroscedasticity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the situation. When you have multiple independent variables, sometimes only one of them has a nonlinear relationship - in this case, transforming the dependent variable may cause problems with the other variables. In some cases, a log transform makes more substantive sense for one or the other variable. If you log transform the DV only then you are saying that arithmetic changes in the IVs relate to geometric changes in the DV. If you transform (some or all) IVs, then just the reverse.  Often, variables related to income or other amounts make more sense log transformed. That is, a change in income from \$20,000 per year to \$40,000 is more like (in some sense) a change from \$200,000 to \$400,000 than a change from \$200,000 to \$220,000. If NONE of your variables can be sensibly log-transformed, it might be better to pursue some non-linear regression such as splines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. All my predictors are in nonlinear relationship with the response (and in linear between each other, highly correlated). My predictors are signals going through a medium with attenuation and response is the distance. The physical background says that the dependence is logarithmic.

Comment: So it is related mainly to the sense of variables, and is not important for the regression accuracy and future prediction of values?

Comment: Sounds like the logical first try is taking log of the DV. It is related to *all* the issues you mention, but a regression that makes no sense is not going to be a good one, usually.

Comment: Thanks! If I'm not mistaken, in the case of transforming the response, I could then back-transform (i.e. exp()) the predicted values and thus return them to the normal physical sense, right?

Answer (score -2):

Doing linear reg. its better to tranform the independent (explanatory ) variable and use the tranformation methods according to your data and cheak r-square for the model and MSE(mean square of error) for the modle if r-square is higher and MSE is mininmum you can say tranformation is appropriate..